# Run Python file SLURM - access data

Tags: python, slurm

everyone! I'm new in this SLURM thing so I'm sorry if this question looks silly.

I have to work with a huge database that can not be saved in my pc, so I've access to SLURM and the data is stored in one directory.

How can I add this data to my Python script to run a model (how can I connect python to the SLURM database)?

Thank you

Comment: You want to connect to SLURM database? Or to the data that is in a folder? Adding the data that you have in a folder works the same way as if it were a small dataset, so you should be doing the same you are currently doing..

Comment: Both, I think. I can see and Access the data through winSCP but I don't know how to make Python read these data.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to the SLURM job management system for computing clusters? 

This is a useful tool for processing large datasets by splitting the processing of a dataset into parts that each node in a cluster can perform in parallel. If you got access to a cluster running SLURM due to the storage connected to that cluster being sufficient to hold the database, you can run your regular python script via srun or use sbatch to run the python script on different parts of the database in parallel (e.g. each job in an array handles processing of one person's data in a database)